# ImportError with py2exe-compiled executable

Tags: python, py2exe, google-cloud-python

I am using py2exe to compile a set of scripts that rely on the Google Cloud Python API.  After compiling, when I run an executable, the following error displays:

```
  ...
  File "<script_name>.py", line xx, in <module>
    import google.cloud
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

I have done some Googling on the general "ImportError" with py2exe, and the answers I am finding do not seem to apply to my problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think that you don't have the google.cloud package installed

Comment: I do have the package installed.  The script works fine when it is not compiled as an EXE.

Comment: google-cloud is not on the [list](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules) of packages that are known to work with py2exe.

Comment: Have you tried using the `--include package` flag? i.e. `python setup.py py2exe --includes google.cloud`

Comment: I tried doing something similar to the [GoogleProtobuf protocol](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/GoogleProtobuf), i.e. creating empty `__init__.py` files.  When I did that, the generated exectuable complained about missing the "appdirs" and "packaging" modules, so I installed those and added those to the "include" tags.  After that, the generated executable complained "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-storage' distribution was not found and is required by the application".  I got stuck at that point.